# Выделение чисел из строки матрицы (Assembler)

Tags: ассемблер, матрицы, вывод, числа, ввод

Всем привет! Хочу выделить числа из строки матрицы разделенной пробелами  и занести их в массив, или хотя бы вывести их. Однако не получается. Вот код :

```
    LOCALS

.model small

.stack 100h

.data
        CrLf            db      0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

        A               dw      8 dup (0)
        SizeA           dw      ($-A)/2

        kbdBuffer       db      6, 0, 6 dup(0)

        start db "start.txt",0
        buf db ?
        Mas_A   dw  100 Dup(?)
        Mas_B   dw  100 Dup(?)
        num db 256 dup('$')

.code

main    proc
        mov     ax,     @data
        mov     ds,     ax

        mov ax,3d00h    ; открываем для чтения
        lea dx,start     ; DS:dx указатель на имя файла
        int 21h     ; в ax деcкриптор файла
        jc exit     ; если поднят флаг С, то ошибка открытия

        mov bx,ax       ; копируем в bx указатель файла
        xor cx,cx
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,4200h
        int 21h     ; идем к началу файла

       out_str:
        mov ah,3fh      ; будем читать из файла
        mov cx,1        ; 1 байт
        lea dx,buf      ; в память buf
        int 21h         
        cmp ax,cx       ; если достигнуть EoF или ошибка чтения
        jnz close       ; то закрываем файл закрываем файл

        cmp buf,'   '
        je isFullNumber

        add dl,buf
        jmp out_str

    isFullNumber:
        ;call Str2Num
        ;call Show_AX
        mov   ah, 9           
        mov   dx,       
        int   21h
        jmp out_str

        ;ввод масива
        ;mov     cx,     [SizeA]
        ;lea     dx,     [A]
        ;вывод массива
        ;call    ShowArray

        close:           ; закрываем файл, после чтения
        mov ah,3eh
        int 21h

       exit:            ; завершаем программу
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
main    endp

;Ввод массива слов (word)
;cx - количество вводимых элементов
;ds:dx - адрес массива слов
InputArray      proc
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    si
        push    di

        jcxz    @@Exit          ;если массив пустой - завершить

        mov     si,     1       ;индекс элемента массива
        mov     di,     dx      ;адрес текущего элемента массива
        @@ForI:
                ;вывод приглашения ввода элемента
                mov     ah,     09h
                lea     dx,     PromptA1
                int     21h
                mov     ax,     si
                call    Show_AX
                mov     ah,     09h
                lea     dx,     PromptA2
                int     21h
                ;ввод числа
                mov     ah, 0Ah ;ввод строки
                mov     dx, offset kbdBuffer
                int     21h
                mov     ah,09h  ;перевод строки (на новую строку)
                lea     dx, CrLf
                int     21h

                push    si
                lea     si, kbdBuffer+1 ; преобразование строки в число
                ;lea     di, Numer
                call    Str2Num
                pop     si

                ; проверка на ошибку
                jnc     @@NoError

                ; если есть ошибка ввода - повторить ввод
                jmp     @@ForI

                ; если нет ошибки ввода - сохранить число
                @@NoError:
                ;сохранение введённого числоа в массиве
                mov    [di],   ax
                ;переход к следующему элементу
                inc     si
                add     di,     2
        loop    @@ForI
@@Exit:
        pop     di
        pop     si
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
InputArray      endp

;Вывод массива слов (word)
;cx - количество выводимых элементов
;ds:dx - адрес массива слов
ShowArray       proc
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    si
        push    di

        jcxz    @@Exit          ;если массив пустой - завершить

        mov     si,     1       ;индекс элемента массива
        mov     di,     dx      ;адрес текущего элемента массива
        @@ForI:
                mov     ax,     [di]
                call    Show_AX
                mov     ah,     02h
                mov     dl,     ' '
                int     21h
                ;переход к следующему элементу
                inc     si
                add     di,     2
        loop    @@ForI
@@Exit:
        pop     di
        pop     si
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
ShowArray       endp

; выводит знаковое 16-разрядное число из регистра AX на экран
; входные данные:
; ax - число для отображения
Show_AX proc
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    di

        mov     cx,     10
        xor     di,     di      ; di - кол. цифр в числе

        ; если число в ax отрицательное, то
        ;1) напечатать '-'
        ;2) сделать ax положительным
        or      ax,     ax
        jns     @@Conv
        push    ax
        mov     dx,     '-'
        mov     ah,     2       ; ah - функция вывода символа на экран
        int     21h
        pop     ax

        neg     ax

@@Conv:
        xor     dx,     dx
        div     cx              ; dl = num mod 10
        add     dl,     '0'     ; перевод в символьный формат
        inc     di
        push    dx              ; складываем в стек
        or      ax,     ax
        jnz     @@Conv
        ; выводим из стека на экран
@@Show:
        pop     dx              ; dl = очередной выводимый символ
        mov     ah,     2       ; ah - функция вывода символа на экран
        int     21h
        dec     di              ; повторяем пока di<>0
        jnz     @@Show

        pop     di
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
Show_AX endp

; преобразования строки в знаковое число
; на входе:
; ds:[si] - строка с числом
; ds:[di] - адрес числа
; на выходе
; ds:[di] - число
; CY - флаг переноса (при ошибке - установлен, иначе - сброшен)
Str2Num proc
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    ds
        push    es
        push    si

        push    ds
        pop     es

        mov     cl, ds:[si]
        xor     ch, ch

        inc     si

        cmp     [si], byte ptr '-'
        jne     @@IsPositive
        inc     si
        dec     cx
@@IsPositive:
        jcxz    @@Error

        mov     bx, 10
        xor     ax, ax

@@Loop:
        mul     bx         ; умножаем ax на 10 ( dx:ax=ax*bx )
        mov     [di], ax   ; игнорируем старшее слово
        cmp     dx, 0      ; проверяем, результат на переполнение
        jnz     @@Error

        mov     al, [si]   ; Преобразуем следующий символ в число
        cmp     al, '0'
        jb      @@Error
        cmp     al, '9'
        ja      @@Error
        sub     al, '0'
        xor     ah, ah
        add     ax, [di]
        jc      @@Error    ; Если сумма больше 65535
        inc     si

        loop    @@Loop

        pop     si
        push    si
        or      ax, ax
        js      @@Error
        cmp     [si+1], byte ptr '-'
        jne     @@Positive
        neg     ax
        or      ax, ax
        jns     @@Error
@@Positive:
        mov     [di], ax
        clc
        pop     si
        pop     es
        pop     ds
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
@@Error:
        xor     ax, ax
        mov     [di], ax
        stc
        pop     si
        pop     es
        pop     ds
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
Str2Num endp 

end     main
```

Чтобы уменьшить зону поиска, вот тут где-то ошибка:

```
main    proc
        mov     ax,     @data
        mov     ds,     ax

        mov ax,3d00h    ; открываем для чтения
        lea dx,start     ; DS:dx указатель на имя файла
        int 21h     ; в ax деcкриптор файла
        jc exit     ; если поднят флаг С, то ошибка открытия

        mov bx,ax       ; копируем в bx указатель файла
        xor cx,cx
        xor dx,dx
        mov ax,4200h
        int 21h     ; идем к началу файла

       out_str:
        mov ah,3fh      ; будем читать из файла
        mov cx,1        ; 1 байт
        lea dx,buf      ; в память buf
        int 21h         
        cmp ax,cx       ; если достигнуть EoF или ошибка чтения
        jnz close       ; то закрываем файл закрываем файл

        cmp buf,'   '   ;ЕСЛИ НАШЕЛ ТАЬУЛЯЦИЮ ЗНАЧИТ ЧИСЛО ПОЛНОЕ
        je isFullNumber

        add dl,buf      ;ДОБАВЛЯЮ ВСЕ ЦИФРЫ ЧИСЛА КОТОРОЕ НАЙДУ В DL
        jmp out_str

    isFullNumber:
        ;call Str2Num
        ;call Show_AX
        mov   ah, 9           
        mov   dx,       
        int   21h
        jmp out_str

        ;ввод масива
        ;mov     cx,     [SizeA]
        ;lea     dx,     [A]
        ;вывод массива
        ;call    ShowArray

        close:           ; закрываем файл, после чтения
        mov ah,3eh
        int 21h

       exit:            ; завершаем программу
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
main    endp
```

Я пытался найти каждую цифру числа и закинуть их в DL, а при встрече табуляции вывести DL.

Comment: Во первых в начале цикла dx используется для передачи значения в int 21h, и в конце цикла (перед следующей итерацией) вы в dl (который половина от dx) сохраняете свое значение. таким образом вы в цикле портите только что сохраненное значение. И когда цикл завершиться то в dl окажется младшая часть адреса загруженного туда lea dx, buf.

Comment: Во вторых, после того как это исправите и будете сохранять значение например в стеке (int 21h портит все регистры) обнаружите другую проблему. У вас в входном файле видимо число представлено символами цифр. например значение 1 это байт со значением 0x31. Если же вам в алгоритме надо работать с ним как с числом то из него надо вычесть 0x30. А что дальше, не понимаю, в задаче не вижу что надо получить именно сумму цифр числа, а сейчас вы пытаетесь получить именно ее. P.S. перед выводом любого числа на экран вам так же потребуется перевести его из двоичного вида в отображаемые символы